# Buscar palabra precisa

Tags: php, mysql

necesito buscar una palabra precisa.
En mi tabla tengo la palabra batidora.
Al momento de escribir la consulta escribo batido, bat.
Y de todas maneras me muestra la palabra batidora.
Es que quiero hacer una condición if.
Que si escribo realmente la palabra batidora.
Me muestre el rsultado.
Y sino pues que no me lo muestre.

Ejemplo:
Meto en una variable la palabra a buscar.
$buscar_palabra ="batido";

Realizó la sentencia sql
$sql ="select usuarios_establecidos from usuarios_establecidos where usuarios_establecidos like '".$buscar_palabra."%' LIMIT 1";

El if por si encontró la palabra batidora.
if ($result->num_rows > 0) {

// output data of each row

while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {

echo "
Palabra encontrada
";

}

} else { echo "palabra no encontrada";}

Comment: Puedes ponerlo así: `$sql="select usuarios_establecidos from usuarios_establecidos where usuarios_establecidos like ' % $buscar_palabra %' LIMIT 1";` NÓTESE que hay un espacio en blanco antes y después de la palabra para *aislarla*. Hay un sólo problema y es que si la columna empieza con el término no funcionará, quizá lo mejor para esto sería usar `RLIKE` que permite implementar REGEX, por ejemplo: `$sql="select usuarios_establecidos from usuarios_establecidos where usuarios_establecidos RLIKE '[[:<:]]$buscar_palabra[[:>:]]' LIMIT 1";`

Comment: Muchas gracias, si me sirvió de mucho su ayuda

Comment: No uses LIKE, LIKE hace referencia a parecido, es decir cualquier cosa que se parezca, para ello utiliza "="

Answer (score 1):

Para que se devuelva la palabra precisa cuando la encontre deves cambiar la sentencia para :

```
 where usuarios_establecidos == '".$buscar_palabra."'
```

he quitado el like y el signo %.

Espero que sea eso que desea.

Answer (score 1):

Una solución simple, pero con algunas limitaciones, sería esta:

```
$sql="select usuarios_establecidos 
      from usuarios_establecidos 
      where usuarios_establecidos like '% $buscar_palabra %' LIMIT 1";
```

NÓTESE que hay **un espacio en blanco antes y después de la palabra** para aislarla. Pero esto sólo funcionará si el término a buscar está en medio, si está al inicio o al final de la columna no será encontrado.

Quizá lo mejor para esto sería usar [`RLIKE`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/regexp.html#operator_regexp) que permite implementar REGEX, por ejemplo:

```
$sql="select usuarios_establecidos 
      from usuarios_establecidos 
      where usuarios_establecidos RLIKE '[[:<:]]$buscar_palabra[[:>:]]' LIMIT 1";
```

---

### Nota sobre la seguridad

Tu consulta es vulnerable a ataques de *Inyección SQL*. Un usuario mal intencionando podría manipular la variable `$buscar_palabra` e inyectar código dañino en el sistema o borrar, alterar, revelar, transferir datos sensibles. Para evitarlo deberías usar consultas preparadas.